# Reference for background needed to study complex geometry

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry

I am going to take a course on complex geometry that follows mostly the first two chapters (chapters 0 and 1) of the book "Principles of Algebraic Geometry" by Griffiths and Harris, and also they recommend as a complement the book "Introduction to Complex Geometry" by Huybrech, they did not specify which parts, but I am guessing the ones that follow the first reference.

I have taken a look of both books and they assume I know a couple of things that I don't, namely:

-Tensor product of linear spaces: They use this for the "complexification" of the tangent space, I have never heard of this construction and I don't know what it is. Also it is used to define multilinear forms, which I haven't worked with either. Huybrecht has a chapter on differential forms, but he assumes that you know the theory for real differential forms.

-De Rahm's cohomology.

-Sheaves and stalks.

-Linear bundles.

Maybe some of the things I listed are easy to search on the internet to get the definition, but I wanted to list them anyway so you can get a better idea of what my background is missing. Also I have a couple of months till the course starts so I have time to read a book/parts of different books, and not only get to know what these things mean but also get used to them and work with them naturally.

And finally, my question: what book(s)/note(s) would you recommend for a just-graduated student to fill these gaps?

Comment: You should take a basic course on differentiable manifolds first.

Comment: You should study real differerential geometry first. I like John M. Lee's book Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. It's very long but includes many details and is very accessible for beginners. This doesn't include sheaves iirc differentiable gemoetry rarely does.

Comment: hi,  Is Lee's book is enough for complex geometry ?